# Добавление в проект на .Net python-модулей и использование их через IronPython

Tags: python, .net, ironpython

Проект на .net 8, возникла идея использовать языковую нейронную сеть BERT в проекте на C# и интегрировать ее с помощью IronPython. Однако такими вещами я не занимался и пока не совсем понимаю, как это правильно сделать. Использую vs studio 2022. Можно ли в solution добавить виртуальную среду python и работать с ней в рамках этого же solution через IronPython?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)